# Setting up a shop as a Facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

Yesterday, a friend told me that Facebook allows users to host a shop as an app.

Is this allowed now?

Where can I find information about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using Facebook Payment

Facebook owns a payment system available through the API to any developer wishing to earn money.

> Facebook Payments is a payment system that offers a safe, easy and
>   fast way to pay for digital and virtual goods in games and apps across
>   Facebook. Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/build/

This payment system is only dedicated to games and app for which we get nothing but some **virtual** goods.

The Payment system doesn't allow you to sell and send anything.

> You may not accept Credits as payment for tangible goods, including as
>   payment for anything that may subsequently be used to acquire tangible
>   goods, defined as any good that is **physically delivered** to a user. Source: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/credits/

Anyway, it would not have been a good idea... see:

> Facebook will earn a **30% service fee,** plus any applicable
>   sales tax or VAT, in connection with each Facebook Payments
>   transaction on our platform. Source: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/credits/

### Using a non-facebook payment system (Paypal, VISA...)

In that case, you are only displaying the content of your site under an app. An app which could be visible on your own domain (www.yourdomain.com) as well as on your Facebook app (www.facebook.com/yourapp). Your website/app could eventually lead to a payment page which is independent from Facebook. So, a webshop through an app is allowed, as soon as it doesn't use Facebook Payment! The only restriction from the Facebook policy is:

> You will not sell or purchase any data obtained from us by anyone. Source: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Comment: Its about 1.5 years ago, that i had my last facebook app. Exacly the points you have written is what i thoght before. But it seems that facebook allowes it now. I found 5 Online-services where you can do that. Here one them : http://www.favourite-solutions.de/shopsystem-fur-facebook/
... or just google for "facebook shopsystem" or "facebook shopsytem service" Im really confused, because i find no official infos about this.

Comment: check this: http://www.facebook.com/Onlinesupermarkt/app_347907105232620

Comment: Yes, it doesn't use Facebook Payment but a usual payment system, like on any other website. I thought you were only making a reference to Facebook Payment. I updated my post.